# Is using a filter of size (1, x, y) on a 3D convolutional layer the same as using a filter of size (x,y) on a 2D convolutional layer?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, keras

I'm trying to predict some properties of videos with Keras using the following rough architecture:

1. Feed each frame through the same 2-D convolutional layer.
2. Take the outputs of this 2-D convolutional layer and feed them through a 3-D convolutional layer.

There are more hidden layers, but these are the main ones that matter and are messing with my dimensionality. The input of `Conv2D` should be `(batch_size, height, width, channels)`. Each movie has dimensionality `(number_of_frames, height, width, channels)`. I first had the idea to neglect batching of movies entirely, and treat the batch size and the number of frames equivalently. Then, `Conv2D` would output a 4-D tensor, and I would increase its dimensionality to make the ouput a 5-D tensor that I could input into `Conv3D`. To do this, `Conv3D` could only accept inputs of batch size 1.

I decided against this, because I wanted to batch movies. My current thought is to do this:

```
conv1 = Conv3D(filters=1, kernel_size =(1,12,12), strides=(1,1,1), data_format='channels_last')
conv2 = Conv3D(filters=1,kernel_size=(10,10,10), strides=(1,1,1), data_format='channels_last')
```

`conv1` would represent the 2-D convolutional layer while `conv2` would represent the 3-D convolutional layer. Would this idea work? I figure there is the advantage that I can batch now and when I train the 2-D filter, the same 2-D filter is running over every single movie frame. I'm just worried that  the filter in `conv1` will fail to go over certain frames, or it will somehow overlap frames when I want the filter to go over every frame individually.

Comment: Could you be more explicit about the properties you want to predict?